# How to select folder for UIDocumentPickerViewController on IOS16 or later

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This SwiftUI code doesn't work. I can't select folder in an app in a sumilator on IOS16.

```
struct FolderPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var folderURL: String?
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return FolderPicker.Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<FolderPicker>) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        let supportedTypes = [UTType.folder,UTType.text]
        let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<FolderPicker>) {}
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        var parent: FolderPicker
        
        init(parent: FolderPicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            guard let url = urls.first else {
                return
            }
            print(url)
            parent.folderURL = url.absoluteString
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how to select folder for UIDocumentPickerViewController on IOS16 or later.

The select button doesn't appear in the circle in the image.

[image]

Comment: `This code doesn't work`. What does not work? What error do you get?

Comment: Welcome to SO.Whats the problem? Did you present that `UIDocumentPickerViewController` with using `self.present(picker,animated:Bool)`?. Can you give some more details about your problem?

Comment: How can I use "self.present(picker,animated:Bool)" in SwiftUI? Sorry, I'm new to SwiftUI...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and it was driving me nuts. I think the problem is

```
let supportedTypes = [UTType.folder,UTType.text]
```

If you just do

```
let supportedTypes = [UTType.folder]
```

you can select a folder. However you won't get a Select button. You have to navigate to the folder you want to access and hit Open. The UI has changed from the way it was prior to iOS 16, and not for the better, IMHO. It is a lot less intuitive for the user.

Comment: And just in case this doesn't drive you nuts enough, when using `UTType.folder`, you cannot select anything inside of a custom FileProvider (OneDrive, DropBox, Readle Documents, FileBrowser Pro, etc).  I'd love to know how to select a folder from inside of one of those using `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, but that's probably best for another question...